# Migration TFS to Visual Studio Team Services - Error with Process Templates

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

I'm trying to do the migration from our TFS 2013 to VS Team Services but I'm facing one issue which is because of the process templates.
I got the error "Template Customization or Template Mismatch Error". Then I have the list of fields in my templates that are not "supported". (The two errors are with "Description HTML" and "Sprint")
To make sure everything works properly, I downloaded the process templates from Visual Studio Team Services and apply it to my TFS. I should have the same Process Templates on both sides.
But when I re-validate the migration summary, it keeps failing for the same reason.

Do you have any idea that would help me moving forward?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What migration tool are you using?

Comment: OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility

Answer (score 0):

You need to completely remove the fields using the command outlined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404864(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try that as soon as the code migration is done (maybe in a day or two :) )